# preserve state of Silverlight view

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am starting developing in silverlight for windows phones. As i understood, the xaml views in silverlight are stateless.

How can i preserve a view with a listbox so that after returning to it, i don't have to reload the data in that view?

Here is an example:

let's say i have some list items that have some photos,text etc. from the internet.
 When clicking on a listbox item i go into a detailed view for the respective item. When i go back,reloading the listbox isn't efficient (from the perspective of time, processing, bandwich etc.). How can i save that view so that i don't have to reload it? Can it  be done?

**UPDATE**: i just started a timer in a view and navigated to another and when i went back, the timer was still running ( it was a Threading.Timer), so does this mean that the views are not stateless and they are not destroyed when navigating to other views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Mat laceys Tombstone helper, it makes saving the state of all Silverlight pages very easy to do, in fact in most cases it is just two lines of code per page to do.

[WP7 Tombstone helper](http://tombstonehelper.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Views may be stateless *by themselves*, but nothing stopping them being bound to states/data that is retained across views. Silverlight is more like a desktop app than an ASP.Net app. *If your timer in a view is still running (which they will), that is because the view is still cached somewhere (or the timer itself is stopping the view from being disposed).*

The problems with state (on a WP7 app) relate more to the limited amount of memory you have, so you need to be careful about what you retain.

If your app is exited and restarted you will need to archive the data in isolated storage instead (if you don't want to re-stream it from the web each time it starts), but for in app retention that is down to what you want to hang on to between views.